# How to effectively provide a token liquidity on uniswap for the first time?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, uniswap

I created 100.000 Tokens, now Id'like to provide liquidity on uniswap with 100$ (0.04 ETH) I have as of now (2022-02-25th), however these are my concerns:

1. What if someone bought all my tokens since it's cheaper (eg. 0.0000001 eth/token)?
2. If someone bought all, Do I just lost my tokens and does the person have power to manipulate the token's market?
3. Do I have to mint a fixed amount of tokens or create unlimited number?
4. Is it a good idea to put a limit on how many tokens per wallet? but one person can have more wallets, I am confused.

Any help?

Comment: I think you should narrow down the scope of the post, and ask just a single question. Also, questions that invite opinion based answers ("is it a good idea...") are not permitted on Stack Overflow. See the [help] center for more information.

Comment: Once you fix the question, asking on ethereum.stackexchange.com/ could give better results.